# What is the equivalent of CFL criterion when using spectral models?

Tags: numerical-modelling, grid-spacing

I would like to know what the equivalent of the [CFL criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant%E2%80%93Friedrichs%E2%80%93Lewy_condition) is for atmospheric models based of spectral grids. In other words, how do you find the necessary horizontal resolution in meters for spectral grids?

Comment: hint - think wavelength